# World distance between objects

Tags: algorithm, opencv, graphics

I have a simulated robotic system where there are 2 vision sensors and 2 objects.

From this sensors I have:
2 images from vision sensors where there are 2 objects
2 depth maps from this vision sensors

I need
to compute distance between these two objects.

Is there such algorithm in opencv or is it somehow easy to compute?
I have found some ways to do it but everywhere they assume that I can calibrate sensors and get different sensor dependant variables which I currently believe I am not able. 
I am not very good at comp. vision so no need to be brief :).
 Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yetti, unfortunately if you want to get 3d distances, you must have your cameras calibrated in some way for them to work together.  There really is no way around it.

Comment: "which I currently believe I am not able. " -- [you are, no fear.](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html)

Comment: Did you try to use stereo vision? http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html#gsc.tab=0